# Rococo reset schedule

Tags: rococo

I apologize for the vague intro in advance :)

Some time ago, I was told by someone or read somewhere that Rococo testnet will reset every so often. By this I mean a complete DB wipe, starting from block **1**.

I tried to find more info about this but haven't managed so far - I'm interested in particular how often does it reset? Is there a schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plan for that.

It depends on if there is an unrecoverable error happened.

Rococo is a place to test the latest parachain features. So we don't know when the new-features/operations will cause an unrecoverable error.

And you could find some other information about Rococo here:
https://github.com/paritytech/subport

Comment: Thanks, I checked the linked repo before but there was no answer to my question.

But if this isn't on a schedule, than that's an answer to my question. Thanks!